Reflective Insulation vs Fiberglass Insulation
I'm planning to tidy up our enclosed basement, which has the ceiling covered in fiberglass insulation batts that are drastically falling out. I am considering whether to:

Add a vapor barrier/house wrap (allows water vapor through, although I've seen disagreements on what side faces the insulation) to push the fiberglass up but I'm worried about moisture accumulation between this vapor barrier and the old insulation.

Replace the whole old insulation batts with reflective insulation. Less hazardous fiberglass dust but I'm unsure about the building code for this kind of insulation i.e. fire retardant. Our house is in MA.


May I ask for your opinions about both options? Pros and cons? Things to consider, etc.

if you basement is enclosed why is there insulation between your basement ceiling and your main floor ?

Wouldn't it be better to insulate the basement walls? Then there wouldn't be any need to insulate the ceiling.

where are you??

@FreshCodemonger we recently purchased the property and it has been like that. We assume its a thing builders do to satisfy building code

@RayButterworth if I have my way, I would not do any insulation at all. But I'm worried about code violations.

@DMoore Massachusetts. I'm reading through their building code at the moment.

"adding a vapor barrier/Tyvek" — Tyvek is the exact opposite of a vapor barrier; it's designed to allow water vapour to pass through.  In use, vapor barriers go on the warm side of the insulation (to prevent water from condensing on the insulation), and Tyvek on the cold side (to allow whatever water vapour is present to escape).

@RayButterworth I totally need to do more research then. OK so a vapor barrier will be what I need.

Since it is Mass... I have to ask what is your basement made out of (poured concrete), how high are the ceilings, is it finished at all, what is the flooring, how tall is it, is your basement damp or does it get water?

@DMoore Sorry this totally fell off my radar. Our basement is made of of Poured Concreate, unfinished, quite dry. Our basement ceiling is about 10ft, right underneath our first floor (which has wooden floor). About the temperature difference, our basement is not heated and cold, while our first floor is heated. If I use 4mil poly sheet to contain the insulation, it would be on the cold side of the insulation - which is not how one supposed to use poly sheeting for. But

But @isherwood mentioned that it's unlikely to cause an issue as long as the floor above isn't completely sealed.

There are any number of methods available to secure batt insulation: stiff wires, netting, string, covering with sheet goods (drywall, plywood, etc.).
The insulating properties of reflective barriers are insignificant, as the great preponderance of heat loss occurs by conduction and convexion. Fiberglass batting also comes in a form enclosed in a plastic sheath, to minimize any released "dust".

I am looking at this Encapsulated Fiberglass Batt that you mentioned, seems like a good option for what we want. About covering/securing batt insulation, I believe the material has to be fire-retardant to abide fire code. We are MORE worried about the fiberglass dust vs its falling off - we just want to fully cover it up or replace it.

Put up polyethylene sheeting. You don't need expensive house wrap, and there's no reason to replace your fiberglass.

Its usual purpose is to prevent condensation where temperature differentials exist. You typically want it on the warm side, but it's unlikely to cause an issue as long as the floor above isn't completely sealed. Most floors aren't.

Poly will contain the fiberglass, which really isn't hazardous unless it's not properly contained.

It's fairly cheap. Use 4 mil so you have enough toughness, and use at least one helper so it comes out flat and neat.



Does it need to be fire retardant? I saw some sources mentioning the cover material needs to be able to withstand fire in case of a basement fire event.

yes it should be fire retardant but that isn't a tough order.
